# Difference of More Like This (MLT) and normal select query in Solr

Tags: select, text, solr, tf-idf

Can someone explain the exact difference of MLT and normal select query in Solr ? I know that Solr uses an advanced form of TF.IDF to score documents based on a select query for a textual field, but how does the scoring algorithm differ when MLT is being used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the question really makes sense - More Like This is used to find more documents similar to one you already have. This is different from entering a query and wanting to get something back, they're used to solve very different modes of operation.

Behind the scenes they're both queries in the meaning of "looks up something in the index based on input", which for MLT is the terms from the existing document, instead of the query the user has entered.

You can see [how the MLT query is built in MoreLikeThis.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/queries/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queries/mlt/MoreLikeThis.java#L618). If I read the code correctly, a PriorityQueue is used to fetch the scores for all the terms, which are then added as boost queries to a large set of terms in a boolean query, where each term is set to SHOULD occur. That way the terms are boosted based on MLT semantics, while it uses the ClassicSimilarity behind the scenes.

But again, the use case for MLT is very different from when you'd use a regular query.

Comment: So I'm still not sure if I got it right but what I understood is that MLT is useful when we want to compare the whole record with another record (?!). But in my case which I want to compare two records based on only one of their fields (name), there is no need for MLT and simple select query can do the thing (right?). Since I was wondering if the results would be better if I use MLT instead of only query the names. (Note that the two records that I'm comparing only have a single feature in common which is "name")

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "compare". If you mean retrieve the document based on a query you want to make, then yes, a query is what you want. MLT is for implementing something like "More articles like this" on a web page, where you have an existing article (the one being read) and want to retrieve documents that are similar to the one you already know. To find a document based on an entered name, a regular query on `name:<term>` is what you want.